# Growth Curve Predictions For New Data

Tags: r, prediction

```
library(lme4)
data(ChickWeight)

CHICKS = as.numeric(unique(ChickWeight$Chick))
TRAIN = sample(CHICKS, 30)
TEST = CHICKS[!(CHICKS %in% TRAIN)]

TRAIN.DAT = ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick %in% TRAIN, ]
TEST.DAT = ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick %in% TEST,]



MODEL = lmer(weight ~ Time + Diet + (1 | Chick), data = TRAIN.DAT)
MODEL_PREDICTION_TRAIN = predict(MODEL)
MODEL_PREDICTION_TEST = predict(MODEL, newdata = TEST.DAT)
```

Basically, I am wondering, how do you obtain predictions for new data? I got error that

```
new levels detected in newdata
```

so how do you get predictions for new data?

Comment: You have a random effect for Chick that you estimate with (1 | Chick). What do you want to do with the random effects in the the new data? If you want to ignore that term than you can do `MODEL_PREDICTION_TEST = predict(MODEL, newdata = TEST.DAT, re.form=~0)` Otherwise if you want to keep that term, you can only predict for those same Chick IDs used during training since there's no way to estimate the random effect for subjects that were not included during training.